# How do I find the contents of a specific Outlook Contacts subfolder?

Tags: c#, outlook, contacts, subdirectory

I need to extract the contacts (Employees) listed in a specified (by name) subfolder in Outlook Contacts.  I've been at it for days, and tried every scrap of code I can find on the internet, but to no avail.  I have seen suggestions about how it *could* be done, but none of them actually work.

Here's my running code.  You can drop it in a console app in Visual Studio as-is.  I can find the contents of my "Contacts" folder, and I can find the list of folders, but can't work out how to get the contents of a sub folder.

We're using Outlook 365.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace OutlookTest
{
    public class OutlookDataRetriever
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();


                Console.WriteLine("\n\nShow Contacts folders:");
                Outlook.MAPIFolder folderContacts = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
                foreach (Outlook.MAPIFolder subfolder in folderContacts.Folders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("folder::: " + subfolder.Name + " ::: " + subfolder.FolderPath);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n\nShow members of Contacts folder:");
                Outlook.MAPIFolder fldContacts = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
                Outlook.Items contactsFolder = fldContacts.Items;
                foreach (var contact in contactsFolder)
                {
                    if (contact is Outlook.ContactItem)
                    {
                        Outlook.ContactItem thisContact = (Outlook.ContactItem)contact;
                        Console.WriteLine("contact::: " + thisContact.FullName + " ::: " + thisContact.Email1DisplayName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("I'm guessing this is a folder, but can't figure out how to cast it to access its contents.");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

My References:
[snapshot of the solution explorer showing references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYWCf.png)

Here's the output I get:

```
Show Contacts folders:
folder::: {06967759-274D-40B2-A3EB-D7F9E73727D7} ::: \\KNye@myOrganization.com\Contacts\{06967759-274D-40B2-A3EB-D7F9E73727D7}
folder::: {A9E2BC46-B3A0-4243-B315-60D991004455} ::: \\KNye@myOrganization.com\Contacts\{A9E2BC46-B3A0-4243-B315-60D991004455}
folder::: Companies ::: \\KNye@myOrganization.com\Contacts\Companies
folder::: GAL Contacts ::: \\KNye@myOrganization.com\Contacts\GAL Contacts
folder::: Kristy Nye[1] ::: \\KNye@myOrganization.com\Contacts\Kristy Nye[1]
folder::: Kristy Nye ::: \\KNye@myOrganization.com\Contacts\Kristy Nye
folder::: Recipient Cache ::: \\KNye@myOrganization.com\Contacts\Recipient Cache
folder::: PeopleCentricConversation Buddies ::: \\KNye@myOrganization.com\Contacts\PeopleCentricConversation Buddies
folder::: Kristy's Addresses ::: \\KNye@myOrganization.com\Contacts\Kristy's Addresses
folder::: Organizational Contacts ::: \\KNye@myOrganization.com\Contacts\Organizational Contacts


Show members of Contacts folder:
contact::: Matt Smith ::: Matt Smith (ESmith@myOrganization.com)
contact::: Kristy J Nye ::: Kristy J Nye (KNye@myOrganization.com)
I'm guessing this is a folder, but can't figure out how to cast it to access its contents.
```

Here's a screenshot of my Contacts folder:
[Screenshot of Contacts folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSy1K.png)

Here's the contents of my folder, "ThisIsATestGroup":[Contents of "ThisIsATestGroup" folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OgmN.png)

My objective:
I want to query "Find all contacts in "ThisIsATestGroup", and get back:

- Edgar B
- Kristy J N
- Rey G M
- Richard D N

How do I get the contacts in this specific subfolder only??? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much pulling of hair and gnashing of teeth, I found my own answer.  Here 'tis:

```
using System;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace OutlookTest
{
    public class OutlookDataRetriever
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myFolder = "ThisIsATestGroup";
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Show members of '" + myFolder + "' list:");

                Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

                /* Get a list of items in the contactsfolder  */
                Outlook.MAPIFolder fldContacts = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
                Outlook.Items contactsFolder = fldContacts.Items;

                /* Find the contacts folder with the name I'm looking for.  MS documentation calls this a DistListItem.  Baffled me for a long time because their UI calls it a contact group. */
                string filter = "[Subject] = '" + myFolder + "'";
                var targetFolder = contactsFolder.Find(filter);
                Outlook.DistListItem myDistList = (Outlook.DistListItem)targetFolder;
                Console.WriteLine("myDistList::: " + myDistList.Subject);

                /* List all the members in my list */
                for (int i = 1; i <= myDistList.MemberCount; i++) // Index starts at 1, not 0 !!!
                {
                    var aMember = myDistList.GetMember(i);
                    Console.WriteLine("      member::: " + i.ToString() + " " + aMember.Name + " ::: " + aMember.Address);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

On my way to the above solution, I found another solution which has the added benefit of allowing you to look through everything in your contacts folder.  Both solutions return the correct result, but I suspect the top one runs faster.

```
namespace OutlookTest
{
    public class OutlookDataRetriever
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

                Console.WriteLine("Show members of 'ThisIsATestGroup' list:");
                Outlook.MAPIFolder fldContactsX = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
                Outlook.Items contactsFolder = fldContactsX.Items;
                foreach (var contact in contactsFolder)
                {
                    if (contact is Outlook.ContactItem)
                    {
                        Outlook.ContactItem thisContact = (Outlook.ContactItem)contact;
                        Console.WriteLine("contact::: " + thisContact.FullName + " ::: " + thisContact.Email1DisplayName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (contact is Outlook.DistListItem)
                        {
                            Outlook.DistListItem thisDistList = (Outlook.DistListItem)contact;
                            Console.WriteLine("distList::: " + thisDistList.Subject);

                            if (thisDistList.Subject == "ThisIsATestGroup")
                            {

                                for (int i = 0; i < thisDistList.MemberCount; i++)
                                {
                                    var aMember = thisDistList.GetMember(i + 1);
                                    Console.WriteLine("      member::: " + i.ToString() + " " + aMember.Name + " ::: " + aMember.Address);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Should never reach this line.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder fldContacts = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
Outlook.MAPIFolder fldEmployees = fldContacts.Folders["Employees"];
foreach (var item in fldEmployees.Items)
{
    Outlook.ContactItem contact = item as Outlook.ContactItem;
    if (contact != null)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("contact::: " + contact .FullName + " ::: " + contact .Email1DisplayName);
    }
    else
    {
       Outlook.DistListItem distList = item as Outlook.DistListItem;
       if (distList != null)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("distList ::: " + distList.DLName);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dmitry.  Unfortunately, I get an error when I run this.  On the 2nd line of your solution, I substituted ["ThisIsATestGroup"] for ["Employees"], because that's the name of my folder.  When I run, it fails on that same line.  The exception it raises is Message = "The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found."  The stack trace reads "   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Folders.get_Item(Object Index)
   at OutlookTest.OutlookDataRetriever.Main(String[] args) in C:\AA-TFSCode\OutlookTest\OutlookTest\Program.cs:line 42".

Comment: continued:    I think the problem might have something to do with some of my folder names appearing as {06967759-274D-40B2-A3EB-D7F9E73727D7}.  I don't seem to be able to access my folder, "ThisIsATestGroup", by name.

Comment: Are you sure ThisIsATestGroup is a folder off the main Contacts folder? Do you see it in the folder tree view in Outlook? Or is it just a distribution list in the Contacts folder?

Comment: Please see my original post, "Here's a screenshot of my Contacts folder".  I navigate there from the 3-dots on the bottom left, then select People.  I then Rt-click in the center panel, and selected "New Contact Group", and added my new group, and then added new members from my address book.

Comment: Short answer:  Yes, it's off the main Contacts folder.

Comment: I figured out its a DistListItem off the Contacts folder.  Now I'm trying to figure out what type the Member[] elements are.

Comment: I got closer to the answer, but still don't have it - please see the code I posted in the answer below.  I still can't extract that list of names.  Thank you!

Comment: Members[i] returns AddressEntry object.